# How to delete an object in a set

Tags: c++, pointers, object, memory, delete-operator

In my C++ program, I create objects in one function using new. These objects are inserted into a set. When I want to remove objects from the set, I use an iterator in a for-loop. When I remove the object from the set, I still need to delete the object to free its memory, correct? I tried using delete, but then I get an error saying that the pointer being freed was not allocated. So how can this be done?

Here is the code where I create the object and then insert it into the set

```
set <myObject> myobjectlist;
myObject *myobject = new myObject;
myobjectlist.insert(*myobject);
```

In another function, I try to remove an object from the set, and free its memory:

```
    for (set<myObject>::iterator i = myobjectlist.begin(); i != myobjectlist.end(); i++)
if (i->myObjectID == myObjectID)
{
    myobjectlist.erase(*i);
    delete &i;
    break;
}
```

This works fine without the 'delete' part. I added it in because I thought that the memory from the object wasn't being freed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're calling the set's `erase()` method, note that *this will call the destructor of the object for you*. After you `erase()` your object, it has already been `delete`d, and thus your second attempt to manually call delete will fail as the pointer is no longer allocated.

For reference, see [this](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/)

Comment: Based on his code snippet this statement is misleading. His set stores the object by value, so what erase is destructing is not what he allocated with new.

Comment: No, because he's deleting by reference this isn't the case. His set contains a copy of his original object's value, which is then found. The value is erased (and destructed) from the set, and then the iterator is attempted to be deleted -- which won't work, as it no longer points to a valid block.

Comment: His code does not attempt to delete the iterator, it attempts to delete the _address_ of the iterator (which is still a valid address, just not one that holds a pointer to something that was allocated with new). But this isn't the point, the code will leak the original object.

Comment: It is the point though - you can't delete something if it wasn't allocated with new. The set deletes the copy, and by attempting to delete the iterator the error is being thrown

Comment: @Ben, That's not the point of his question as I took it. Even if we corrected that, it would still leak memory. Is the goal to make it run, or make it correct?

Comment: When I initially answered the question, there was no code - just everything before the "So how can this be done?" question. At that time, the answer was "You can't (or shouldn't)", backed up by the above. Now that there's code, I appreciate that the question may have changed. My approach would still leak memory, but would run, which was what I interpreted the OP as originally asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to delete objects that you create.  However, what is in your set isn't necessarily what you allocated.  For example, maybe your set contains object values (rather than pointers) and your allocated object is being leaked after insert.  Post code.

Edit:
That was it.  Your set does not store pointers, it stores copies of the objects you are allocating.  Remove the delete from your erase loop and insert the object like this:

```
set <myObject> myobjectlist;
myobjectlist.insert(myObject());
```

Alternatively, just make your set be `set<myObject*>`.

Also, erase takes an iterator - no need to deref it.

Comment: Making those changes causes compile errors in the for-loop. How should it be changed?

Comment: If it stores copies, then maybe it's ok not to use new when creating the object?

Comment: Either way you can't then delete an element that you have `erase()`d. The erase member calls the destructor of the object, and delete will attempt to do the same thing!

Comment: Right - remove both the new and the delete.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you want, assuming that you need to use new to allocate these objects:

```
  set <myObject*> myobjectlist;     
  myObject *myobject = new myObject;
  myobjectlist.insert(myobject); //insert the pointer, not the object

  for (set<myObject*>::iterator i = myobjectlist.begin(); i != myobjectlist.end(); i++) {
    if ((*i)->myObjectID == myObjectID) {
      myobjectlist.erase(i);
      delete *i;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @sean, erase does not increment the iterator. In fact, erase takes this parameter by value, so it cannot have any effect on your iterator object at all.

Comment: For clarity, calling erase will change the set and therefore invalidate the iterator for further use within the set. However, the iterator itself remains unchanged and can still be used to retrieve the pointer to the object that was just erased.

Comment: my confusion was based on the vs2010 implementation of erase - set::erase returns void, but it is implemented via _Tree::erase which does return an incremented iterator

Answer (score 2):

If you need a list of pointers, use a list of smart pointers. 
Use a std algoritm to find the correct item and erase it from the list.

```
#include <set>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyObject> t_object;
std::set<t_object> myObjectList;
myObjectList.insert(t_object(new MyObject));

std::set<t_object>::iterator item = std::find_if(
    myObjectList.begin(), 
    myObjectList.end(), 
    bind(&MyObject::myObjectID, _1)== myObjectID);
if(item!=myObjectList.end())
    myObjectList.erase(item);
```