# Delete from set by first parameter

Tags: c++

I am storing a struct inside set . The struct contains five variables, including an ID.

```cpp
struct car{int ID;.....} 
set<car>s;
```

I want to delete a car from the set given a particular ID. Suppose ID is x , then delete that car which has ID has x.(All car IDs are distinct no duplicates).
Is it possible to do it in O(log n) time ?

Comment: How about storing the `car`s in a `std::map<int, car>` ? deleting an entry is guaragteed to be O(log n).

Comment: @wohlstad yes thats one solution.

Comment: Related: [How to delete an object in a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838922/how-to-delete-an-object-in-a-set)

Comment: How is your comparison operator defined? The one that is used to order the elements in the set. If it compares IDs, you could just overload it to compare to int and use [`set::erase` (4)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase)

Answer (score 1):

To lookup by ID, you will need to have a transparent compare. By default, `std::set` doesn't use one, so you will need to change the definition of your set.

```
struct id_less {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const car & lhs, const car & rhs) { return lhs.ID < rhs.ID; }
    bool operator()(const car & lhs, int rhs) { return lhs.ID < rhs; }
    bool operator()(int lhs, const car & rhs) { return lhs < rhs.ID; }
}

std::set<car, id_less> cars;

if (auto it = cars.find(x); it != cars.end()) cars.erase(it);
```

In C++23 we will get an overload of erase that uses the transparent compare, so it will become

```
cars.erase(x);
```

Comment: Hello Caleth, Thanks for your answer. I am using a custom comparator so my set is
`set<car,cmp>s`

Comment: @learner what's the definition of `cmp`? Does it just have the first of my `operator()`?

Comment: Yes there is operator in my cmp defintion 
`bool operator()(const car a, const car b) const
 {  }`

Comment: @learner oh, that's unfortunate. You can't keep that ordering *and* have lookup by ID, in `std::set`. If you have access to the boost library, you can use `boost::multi_index_container` to have both sorted-by-time and lookup-by-id.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [**`std::map`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for that purpose, where the ID of the `car` object serves as a **key**:

```
std::map<int, car> s;  // key: car ID, value: car
```

Erasing an element from a `std::map` by a given key can be done in **O(log n)** with [**`std::map::erase`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

```
int id = ...
auto n = s.erase(id);
assert(n == 1);
```

**Note** that `std::map::erase` returns the number of erased elements for error checking.

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This has the disadvantage that the ID in the `car` can be different to the key of the map

Comment: On the other hand it's simple and straight-forward. but I agree there's also a disadvantage here.